# Spring Security OAuth and Cucumber access denied

Tags: spring, spring-security, cucumber, spring-security-oauth2

I've read the whole day articles about how to connect Spring Security OAuth with Cucumber, but none of them matched my usecase, I've just seen people having the same question:

The goal is to be able to access "restricted" API endpoints from within cucumber scenarios, and not getting annoying 401 errors as the @PreAuthorize method denies access. This is quite similar to @WebMvcTest tests using MockMvc, where you can easily inject the security filter chain and it does not even care about being OAuth or not in the background, as the filter chain is not the real one.

So when it comes to cucumber, I want to be able to have a simple test annotated with

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

that can use something like @WebMvcTest's @WithMockUser(...), but this obviously does not work, as in the OAuth security filter chain, a real jwt token is expected and I am operating on API-endpoints (so it is some sort of blackbox):

So I could post now all sort of code, but I assure you the security config is really basic setup of a SpringSecurity configuration like the following, trying to authenticate within a cucumber scenario:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, rsp, e) -> rsp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage()))
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
}
```

I thought about the following solutions, but none of them either is a real solution or worked:

- Disable security in cucumber testing context: the 401 would be gone, but I could not test any ACL, so this is really not what I want
- Trying the @WithMockUser, like in MockMvc: not working
- trying to create a fake jwt in test and adding it to the feign client: well, faking OAuth2AuthenticationDetails is a mess within the interceptor
- trying to set "SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)" in step definitions: well, this fails in security filter chain, and would also fail if I directly called underlying service.

So maybe someone out there knows a solution about this very common problem of how to authenticate a scenario in cucumber using Spring Security OAuth, *assuming* that there is no real authorization server somewhere to talk to as it is no end-to-end test. So I guess I have to go with the way of creating a "test JWT" and attach it to the feign client request, but how can this be done? Generating is not the problem, but how to attach it correctly, if this was the preferred way?

When I am removing the @PreAuthorize annotation from within the controller, and change the ".antMatchers("/**").authenticated()" to ".antMatchers("/**").anonymous()", then it is working. ..